# Add column's default as Base64Encoding of another column value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to create a table that has a column value converted to base64, I want to add another column to a table and I want to default it to casted string value of the first column. Is this possible?

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Students]
(
    [Id] INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY, 
    [StudentAuth] VARCHAR(MAX) NULL,     
    [StudentCastedAuth] VARCHAR(MAX) NULL DEFAULT CAST(CAST(StudentAuth as XML ).value('.','varbinary(max)') AS varchar )
)
```

It says I cannot use StudentAuth in the default value

Comment: No, a `DEFAULT` constraint cannot use another column as input. You could use a computed column instead, were it not for the fact that XML methods aren't allowed in definitions of computed columns, but you can wrap this in a function (`StudentCastedAuth AS dbo.VarCharToBase64(StudentAuth)`). Note that your current implementation won't work unless `StudentAuth` is valid XML, containing a single node with a Base64 string inside, and then it *decodes* that value. You probably want something else.

Comment: Have you considered using a trigger?